# Not able to disassemble iOS Banking app

Tags: ios, disassembly, ida, hopper

I use hopper disassembler to disassemble iOS apps. It works fine for most of the apps.

However today I just got curious to understand a banking app so I tried to disassemble it. So, I moved the app from my jailbroken device to my mac and when I tried to disassemble it with hopper it just gives me some useless stuff.

[image]

Why is this happening? Is the binary of this banking app encrypted? If yes then how can I decrypt it?

What do they exactly do to obfuscate code ? How does their code differs from other applications code ?

I used iFunbox to get executable of app from my iPhone to my mac. All apps exported in this way have no problem while disassembling. So i think iFunbox does DRM removal. Only this particular banking apps does n't work.

I even tried class dump and it gave me only one file named CDStructures.h with nothing in it.

Comment: Given that it's a banking app the code might be obfuscated in some way.

Comment: What do they exactly do to obfuscate code ? Is there any way to view actual assembly instructions? How does their code differs from other applications code ? I even tried class dump and it gave me only one file named CDStructures.h.

Comment: There are tools to obfuscate method names, e.g. using macros. They could also just use C. Without seeing the app it's a bit hard to say.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to remove iOS app encryption (called [FairPlay](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FairPlay)). Since you have device with jailbreak you can do this. There is at least [one tool](https://github.com/KJCracks/Clutch) for doing this.

If you are in doubt about encrypted IPA or not you can use this command:

```
otool -l BINARY | grep -A 4 LC_ENCRYPTION_INFO
```

Also keep in mind that in some countries disassembling maybe be illegal.

Comment: What is wrong with my answer? I don't see any information about removed FairPlay in original question.

Comment: I used iFunbox to get executable of app from my iPhone to my mac. All apps exported in this way have no problem while disassembling. So i think iFunbox does DRM removal. Only this particular banking apps does n't work.

Comment: FairPlay seemed to be used to encrypt audio files (MP4) rather than applications.

Comment: @JackG. all IPA files you install from AppStore are encrypted. You can't disassemble app without removing FairPlay.

Comment: @JohnTracid you are right , I ran otool -l BINARY | grep -A 4 LC_ENCRYPTION_INFO on the binary and it gave me                           
      cmd LC_ENCRYPTION_INFO_64
      cmdsize 24
     cryptoff 16384
    cryptsize 5619712
      cryptid 1.   Note that cryptid is non-positive so app is encrypted and I have to decrypt the executable.  
For more info http://iphonedevwiki.net/index.php/Crack_prevention

Answer (score 3):

At the RSA show in SF (2017), I ran into a company that has a product for obfuscating iOS and Android code.  They demoed a scenario where a webpage can jailbreak a handset without the user's knowledge and patch an application to send banking credentials to a third party whilst appearing to mostly work for the user.  This presents enough of a weakness for there to be at least 2 tools on the market to deal with it (Arxan and Preemptive as far as a quick google yields).  I was surprised by the sophistication level, but apparently it is an attack vector that is worth mitigating for companies with high value and high sensitivity ... like a banking app.  Wouldn't surprise me at all if they were doing this.